# Is it wrong to "imagine" a one when thinking about exponentiation? (e.g. $3^2 = 1 \times 3 \times 3$)

Tags: soft-question, exponentiation

This might be a bit of a basic question, but I'm going through Khan Academy to refresh my math skills in order to pursue a self-study of higher mathematics, so I'm really focused on the "why" of the rules.

One thing that has been bothering me is that I've been imagining a $1$ in front of the expanded form of an exponentiation. I haven't seen it described anywhere, but it's the only way it makes logical sense to me, so I wanted to check that I wasn't making some huge error.

I think the most obvious example of this is for fractional bases with negative exponents, since I need to "force" the reciprocal of the first iteration of the base.

Take $\frac{2}{3}^{-3}$ as an example. Without the imaginary $1$, my brain wants to evaluate it like this

$$\frac{2}{3}^{-3} = \frac{2}{3} \div \frac{2}{3} \div \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} = \frac{18}{12} = 1\frac{1}{2}$$

This is obviously wrong.

If I add the imaginary $1$, everything works out fine:

$$\frac{2}{3}^{-3} = 1 \div \frac{2}{3} \div \frac{2}{3} \div \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{1} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} = \frac{27}{8} = 3\frac{3}{8}$$

Am I missing something terribly obvious, or is this a common way to look at the problem (or an uncommon way to describe a common understanding)? I'm assuming that the concept of $n^0 = 1$ will play into this somewhere.

Comment: Your 'imaginary $1$' is always there. $2=\frac21$

Comment: @Alizter *Your ;)

Comment: @Alizter I suppose that's true, but it feels more counter-intuitive to me here. I can easily visualize $\frac{2}{1}$ so maybe I'm just not visualizing exponentiation correctly.

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is "wrong" is that you only have 1 way to conceptualize mathematical concepts.  Most useful mathematical concepts can be thought of in many different ways.

Comment: @DanielV I guess that's true, but it's somewhat unintentional. I don't really mind having multiple ways of getting to the same answer (I prefer it, really), but I still need to learn when to stop digging and accept the answer I have. My problem in this case is that I've never seen it written with my magic $1$, so I thought I could be missing something about it that would break things later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nice thing about an 'imaginary' $1$ before an exponent expression is it makes it obvious why, for instance, $2^0=1$ ($2^0=1$, with $0$ following factors of $2$, but the $1$ is still there).

This works so well because $1$ is the multiplicative identity--it's like a blank slate for multiplication.  Whatever you multiply by next, the result is itself (what you multiplied by).  It also is a way of seeing why $0! = 1$.

Comment: So is it wrong to use the "imaginary" $1$? @AlexR's explanation has me questioning my understanding of negative exponents (where I use the basis of "subtract 1 from the exponent means divide by the base", but it almost seems like two ways of saying the same thing. Your explanation makes me feel like the "imaginary" $1$ is an acceptable understanding though, so I'm back to questioning my understanding entirely...

Comment: I don't see why you can't use an 'imaginary' $1$ before an exponent expression.  For instance $2^{-3}=1\div 2\div 2\div 2$ works just fine. Having said that, one should check that it works correctly in new situations.

Comment: Accepted for introducing me to the concept of an identity element. This is exactly what I needed for this question as it answers my "what is this imaginary $1$ I keep introducing" question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can always multiply anything by $1$ without changing it's value. This is what we do when extending fractions, for example:
$$\frac12 = \frac12 \cdot \frac22 = \frac24$$
However, you main problem seems to be the definition of
$$x^{-k} = \frac1{x^k}$$
If you write this correctly with divison, you end up with
$$\left(\frac23\right)^{-3} = \frac1{\frac23} \cdot \frac1{\frac23} \cdot \frac1{\frac23} = \frac32\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac32 = \frac{27}8$$
It is simply *not* true that $x^{-k} = \underbrace{x\div x \div \ldots  \div x}_{k \text{ times}}$

Comment: This is simultaneously incredibly helpful and incredibly unnerving. Understanding negative exponents is something else I had to sort of struggle through to find the "why", and I guess I messed up. I guess I'll have to take a step back and try to work through it again. This was so much easier before I started questioning the "why". :)

Comment: I just re-read your answer and I think I should clarify something. I didn't really mean to imply that I legitimately thought $x^{-k} = \underbrace{x\div x \div \ldots  \div x}_{k \text{ times}}$. I was just meaning to use that as an illustration that something was missing for me. It was the simplest example I could think of to explain my trouble finding  a "starting point" for exponentiation.

Comment: I just realized that your explanation has the exact same "imaginary $1$", just written in a different way. Your series of $\frac1{\frac23}$ is the same my answer, only mine is a later version of yours, after multiplying by $\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{\frac{3}{2}}$ to remove the denominators. I feel much better now.

Comment: @AgentConundrum Well, you could see it that way indeed. It's probably best to think of negative exponents as the reciprocal of the corresponding positive exponentiation.

Comment: I do, I was just trying to find the "why" in it all. I think I just ended up digging further than I needed to. I want you to know that I upvoted you, and this answer really helped me with my overall conceptualization. Unfortunately, I think I need to accept @paw88789's answer over yours, because the concept of (multiplicative) identity was the part that really answered my "imaginary $1$" question.

Comment: "$x^{-k} = \underbrace{x\div x \div \ldots  \div x}_{k \text{ times}}$"  but it *is* okay to think of "$x^{-k} = 1\div \underbrace{x\div x \div \ldots  \div x}_{k \text{ times}}$"  (if k is positive).  The OP more or less understands negative expontents.  fraction form of division ($\frac{2}{3}$ rather than $2\div3$) Makes the "magic" one implicit in $x^{-k} = \frac{1}{x^{-k}}$ whereas $x^{-k} = 1\div \underbrace{x\div x \div \ldots  \div x}_{k \text{ times}}$ requires the "magic one" need to be explicit.  But just like a "0" is always there for -2 = 0 - 2, and 5=0+5, the "1" is always there.